# c++ <vector> does not name a type

Tags: c++, c++11, types

So I'm having some type problems in my c++ program.
Here is the code:

```
#include "NHSFileparser.h"
#include "NHSFileController.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>       

std::string databasepath = "/media/sf_Documents/Skola/MVK/testdb/";
std::string dblang = "english";
std::vector<std::string> directories;
std::string directory1 = "/media/sf_Documents/Skola/MVK/testdata/";
std::string directory2 = "/media/sf_Documents/Skola/MVK/testdata2/";
directories.push_back(directory1);
directories.push_back(directory2);
std::vector<std::string> queryterms;
std::vector<std::string> return_files;

int main() {
NHSFileController fc(directory1, databasepath);
bool b = fc.addDirectory(directory1);
NHSDatabase database(databasepath, dblang);
split( queryterms, "test", boost::is_any_of("_")); //Split on lots of chars
std::cout << "Queryterms set." << std::endl;
database.query(queryterms, return_files);
std::cout << return_files.size() << std::endl;
if (return_files.size() > 0){
    std::cout << "File found: " << return_files[0] << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

And when I compile using `g++ 4.6` and `-std=c++0x` on Ubuntu 12.04 I get the following error:

```
    error: ‘directories’ does not name a type
```

on both lines trying to push_back to directories vector.

Everything I've found so far is problems with not declaring std::vector properly, which I (to the extent of my knowledge) have done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot put statements outside functions, only declarations and definitions. Put your code inside `main`.

Answer (score 4):

```
directories.push_back(directory1);
```

Code statements like that can only go inside functions.

In C++11, you can initialise the vector in its declaration:

```
std::vector<std::string> directories {"...", "..."};
```

If you're stuck in the past, then you could move the `push_back` statements inside `main`, or use something like the [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/assign/doc/index.html) library, or write a function to return a populated vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> make_directories() {
    std::vector<std::string> directories;
    directories.push_back("...");
    directories.push_back("...");
    return directories;
}

std::vector<std::string> directories = make_directories();
```